# Some problems after running ubuntu tweak application

Tags: ubuntu-tweak

I downloaded the ubuntu tweak application. After that application has clean some file, the application it self is not starting now..

I am quiet new to linux much and fear that if the tweak application has cleaned some files which were necessary. Is there anything i can fix these problems or short of auto-recovery,

i have got some more leads: here seems to be the error but not sure how can i fix this.

```
buntu-tweak:2887): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-tweak", line 122, in <module>
    from ubuntutweak.main import UbuntuTweakWindow
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/main.py", line 40, in <module>
    from ubuntutweak.preferences import PreferencesDialog
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/preferences.py", line 32, in <module>
    from ubuntutweak.factory import WidgetFactory
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/factory.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ubuntutweak.gui.widgets import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/gui/widgets.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ubuntutweak.settings.compizsettings import CompizSetting
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/settings/compizsettings.py", line 3, in <module>
    import ccm
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/settings/ccm/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Conflicts import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/settings/ccm/Conflicts.py", line 25, in <module>
    from Constants import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/settings/ccm/Constants.py", line 77, in <module>
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 539, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

Comment: Please post ONE question per post. Kindly separate the various issues in separate posts.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is pretty old, but I don't see any answers to this problem.  I only see one question and it seems pretty clear, so I don't understand the criticism made by "To Do" regarding posting one question at a time.

Anyways I had a similar problem with the same locale.Error message.  As nobody bothered to respond to or redirect from this question, I figured it out on my own.  It's an error in python, see here for a solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547631/python-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting

See the response over at stackoverflow by Bakuriu for full explanation, but basically from the terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T) type

sudo apt-get install language-pack-[id]
where [id] is replaced by the language code you can find online (for english it is "en-base" without the quotes.)

After that finishes type:

sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales

...and if your problem was the same as mine, Ubuntu Tweak should run just fine (enter ubuntu-tweak in the terminal to test.)